# Lamba execution role - access denied when calling putObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function role, with the S3FullAccess policy attached.

When I go to try and upload a file to my S3 bucket (on the same account), I get a 403 response saying access was denied. However, looking further into the logs I can see this error popping up

```
InvalidAccessKeyId (client): The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

The log shows that the request is using a temporary key (prefixed with ASIA), but this doesn't show up in any cloudtrail logs.

I have also tried testing from my local machine - assume the same role as the lambda environment and call `aws s3api put-object ...` and it works fine (go figure).

I'm really at my wits end as to why this doesn't work, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit (more info):**

The lambda is sitting behind an API gateway. The request is made to an endpoint for handing uploads which is using the `flysystem-aws-s3-v3 AwsS3Adapter` for handing the uploads

Comment: "When I go to try and upload a file" - does "I" mean "the lambda"?

Comment: Yes, the lambda is running an API, which has an upload endpoint. When I try and call this endpoint I get an access denied error

Comment: Did you set the region of the s3 bucket in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am setting AWS_DEFAULT_REGION to the same region that the bucket is assigned to and the lambda lives in

Comment: For S3 access from a Lambda in the same region and account you shouldn't need any further configuration.  Are you setting anything else besides AWS_DEFAULT_REGION?   What log are you seeing the ASIA identity in?

Comment: That particular log in coming through the log group for the actual lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I've finally worked it out. I was not handing the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` environment variable in my code.